# Como crear una función PHP o Jquery para imprimir Ticket sin dialogo?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

He tenido una eventualidad, estoy desarrollando un **sistema de turnos** para un establecimiento donde pretende que se imprima la información del **turno** recogida con **PHP**. Me gustaría llevar esta información del **ticket** a una **mini impresora** o **impresora de ticket** sin tener que esperar el dialogo de impresión de las paginas web e intentado con librerías  como **printarea.js** pero esta me muestra el dialogo y lo necesito que automáticamente registre en la base de datos e imprima

Answer (score 1):

de entrada te comento, lo que quieres hacer no es posible dado que desde el navegador no tienes acceso al hardware, por eso inevitablemente se ve el dialogo de impresión, pero, lo que hemos hecho algunas ocasiones es lo siguiente:

Creamos un cliente de escritorio que corra en segundo plano en el equipo, entiendo que desde que haces lo del ticket, es por que el sistema será un punto de venta o algo parecido, entonces, en la maquina donde usarán el sistema será necesario instalar el cliente. El cliente levanta un servidor web por ejemplo en el puerto 8000, y éste servidor recibe peticiones ajax, procesa la información, y se comunica directamente a la impresora de tickets, de esta manera, cuando desde javascript quieras imprimir, lo que haces es enviar una petición ajax al puerto 8000 con los parametros que necesitas que se impriman, el cliente los recibe e imprime el ticket.

Comment: entonces amigo poniendo que uso xampp servidor local apache como podria tener un cliente sencillo para windows que resiviera mis peticiones de javascript lo digo si me puedes ayudar por que me e enfocado en web y desconosco como lograr lo que me dices

Comment: o si no puedes proprias decirme como hacer que aunque salga la ventana no debas preciosar que salga la ventana no me impota si no que no haya que presionarla

Comment: Dependen del lenguaje, mira, acá la idea es que tu ya no uses el administrador de impresión como tal del navegador, sino que haces uno propio utilizando el SDK de la impresora, puedes levantar un servidor web con C# por ejemplo, como el de éste [tutorial](https://rlbisbe.net/2011/04/25/creando-un-servidor-http-basico-con-c/), y desde ahí escuchar cuando alguien necesite imprimir, el lenguaje que uses dependerá del SDK de la impresora, desafortunadamnete la mayoria vienen en DLL.